# IQueryable.GroupBy override throws for int and bool, but not for strings

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate, generics

I have a first draft for an extension method on IQueryable with an override for GroupBy which should group by a named property.

Before you ask, I'm not using the Dynamic Expression API aka Dynamic Linq because I couldn't figure out how to access a count for each group with that. The GroupBy method in that library returns a non-generic `IQueryable`, rather than an `IQueryable<IGrouping<>>` that I need for my counts. If there is a way to get at the counts through that library, I'll be happy to accept an answer showing me how. Perhaps some sort of syntax that I couldn't find the documentation for in the `string elementSelector` parameter?

The code:

```
    public static IQueryable<IGrouping<object, T>> GroupBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName)
    {
        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), String.Empty);
        MemberExpression property = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propertyName);
        LambdaExpression group = Expression.Lambda(property, param);

        MethodCallExpression call = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "GroupBy",
            new[] { typeof(T), property.Type },
            source.Expression,
            Expression.Quote(group));

        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<IGrouping<object, T>>(call);
    }
```

I consume it like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories(IQueryable<T> entities, string property)
    {
        var haba = entities.GroupBy(property);
        var categories = haba.Select(group => new Category(group.Key.ToString(), group.Count()));
        return categories.ToArray();
    }
```

And it workes fine as long as my property is of type string. However, if I attempt to use it on an int or bool property I get something like the following error on the call to CreateQuery:

> Argument expression has type
>   System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,DerivedEntity1]]
>   when type
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Object,DerivedEntity1]]
>   was expected. Parameter name: expression

I notice that it's expecting an `IEnumerable` generic rather than an `IQueryable`, which is strange. But a pretty good tip. You can't cast `IEnumerable` to an `IQueryable` without doing an `AsQueryable()`. The question then is, why is it giving me an `IEnumerable` instead of an `IQueryable`? An why isn't it failing in the same way when I pass in a propertyName for a string property?

I should mention that my `IQueryable`'s are instances of `NhQueryable`, from NHibernate, that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think boxing from value types is missing from your code:

```
public static IQueryable<IGrouping<object, T>> GroupBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName)
{
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), String.Empty);
    MemberExpression property = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propertyName);
    UnaryExpression convert = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));
    LambdaExpression group = Expression.Lambda(convert, param);

    MethodCallExpression call = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "GroupBy",
        new[] { typeof(T), typeof(object) },
        source.Expression,
        Expression.Quote(group));

    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<IGrouping<object, T>>(call);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your method definition to include another generic type like so

```
public static IQueryable<IGrouping<O, T>> GroupBy<O, T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName)
{    
   return source.Provider.CreateQuery<IGrouping<O, T>>(call);

}
```

consume it like:

```
var haba = entities.GroupBy<int, Category>(property);
```

Comment: Doesn't work since I would have to infer the O type at run-time by reflection on T with propertyName. And generics need to be determined at compile time. Unless I'm missing something..?

Comment: @Mithon - You don't need to do anything at runtime. You are specifying the type at compile time. *entities.GroupBy<int, Category>(property)*

Comment: no.. cause sometimes propertyName will correspond to a property of type O=string, sometimes O=int, sometimes O=DateTime etc etc.. and which one it is depends on what I send as a string going to a webservice which is passing that string named propertyName.